# Accessing PDO's execute() from a db class

Tags: php, class, pdo

How can one access PDO's execute() method from inside a db class? Below is a snippet of my class and method:

```
class db extends PDO {
        public $memcache;

        function execute($params='') {
            try {$foo=parent::execute($params);}
            catch (PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
            return $foo;
        }

        function __construct($db='server_en',$host='localhost',$uz='root',$pw='') {
            try {
                parent::__construct("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host",$uz,$pw);
                parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
            $this->memcache=new Memcache;
            $this->memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die('Could not connect to Memcache server');
        }
    }
```

I have tried executing the following code:

```
var_dump($db->execute('INSERT INTO `foo`(`bar`) VALUES (0)'));
```

And got the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in ...`.

Could anyone please supply a simple example of how this can be fixed? I am fairly inexperienced with both PDO and classes, so the simpler the answer the better.

P.S. The reason for me replicating *some* of PDO's methods is easier migration to a new db handler when PDO becomes outdated. This is not premature optimization; this is making life easier from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call [`::execute()` on a PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), not PDO itself.

Comment: Thanks! This explains a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

[`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) does not have an `execute` method. It's called [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php). `PDOStatement` does have an [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method, but you need to create such an object first.